# React-Router: How to redirect Route to another url conditionally?

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router

Using React Route, but I am facing this issue: under certain condition I need the app to load a different url than the exact one. Here is what I did:

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { history } = this.props;
    let loadExact = true;

    if (my_condition === true) {
      loadExact = false;
    }

    return (
      <Dashboard history={history}>
        <Switch>
          {
           loadExact ? <Route exact path="/app" component={MainPage} /> : 
           (
              <Redirect to={{
                  pathname: "/app/theotherpage",
                  state: {from: history}
                }} 
              />
           )
          }

          <Route path="/app/theotherpage" component={TheOtherPage} />

          <Route component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
      </Dashboard>
    );
  }
}
```

What I need is if `loadExact` is `false` then redirect to `/app/theotherpage` and therefore load it instead of `/app`. This way it goes to an entirely blank page and it tells me:

> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.

How can I solve this?

Comment: try usinng `history.push()`. It also says you are not doing cleanup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Prakash Reddy Potlapadu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9432518/prakash-reddy-potlapadu) suggested, I used `history.push`. Here is the code:

```
componentDidMount() {
   if (my_condition) {
      history.push("/app/theotherpage");
   }
}
```

And that's it. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it:

1. Through Redirect outside of `<Switch>`

   if (my_condition === true) {
             loadExact = false;
         loadComp = ;
       }

   ```
   return (
     <Dashboard history={history}>
      {loadComp}
       <Switch>
         <Route exact path="/app" component={MainPage} />
         <Route path="/app/theotherpage" component={TheOtherPage} />
         <Route component={NotFound} />
       </Switch>
     </Dashboard>
   );
   ```

   }
   }
2. Through history.push

   `class Application extends React.Component {
     render() {
       const { history } = this.props;
       let loadExact = true;

   ```
   if (my_condition === true) {
     loadExact = false;
     this.props.history.push('/app/theotherpage');
   }

   return (
     <Dashboard history={history}>
       <Switch>
         <Route exact path="/app" component={MainPage} />
         <Route path="/app/theotherpage" component={TheOtherPage} />
         <Route component={NotFound} />
       </Switch>
     </Dashboard>
   );
   ```

   }
   }`

Comment: your second option is not working at all. but the first one I am unable to understand it, can you reelaborate it?